# real cleanup in Doctrine2 iteration

Tags: doctrine-orm, batch-processing

I've read the manual, but it doesn't seem to work that way. I'm iterating over a large dataset, processing statistics. My memory usage explodes and nothing I do stops it.

I've tried detaching, clearing, unsetting, calling gc_collect_cycles and dancing naked under the full moon - nothing even makes a difference.

I have a complex dataset with many relations, lots of whom get pulled into memory during processing, so I'm pretty sure that's the culprit, there's probably a cyclic reference or 10 somewhere.

What I need is something that tells Doctrine to throw away everything it has in memory right now, stop trying to be smart, and start from scratch in the next iteration with nothing except the iteration result itself. NOTHING.

em->clear() doesn't do that. In fact, some test runs reveal that clearing, detatching - really makes no difference in my case.

Is there a way to tell Doctrine to stop being greedy and keeping twenty million objects nobobody cares about anymore in its hands?

Comment: do you use `extra-lazy` associations?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can see, they are not traversed in the relevant code sections.